# get CTR or clicks/Impressions via sisense from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, sisense

I have CTR, clicks in the Google analytics. I want to get these data via sisense. According to the instruction https://documentation.sisense.com/7-1/managing-data/connectors/google-analytics.htm#gsc.tab=0 I use elastiCube manager to create an ElastiCube. I use google analitics web service to add the data to ElasiCube. I got 27 tables with names like: Traffic By Navigation, Monthly Report, Traffic By Navigation, Monthly Report and so on. By they do not have the fields which I need. I go to google analitics account via Behavior->Events->Overview. I can see "Clicks". How can I get it via sisense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find an example for adding event fields with XML: https://support.sisense.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007407787-Tracking-Sisense-Usage-Via-Google-Analytics

Comment: Thanks. It was very usefull.